# Get the difference between dates in the form of list years and months

Tags: python, datetime, date

Sorry for my english.

I have a two dates(DateTime):

`latest_client = Client.objects.all().latest('id').ordered_at

first_client = Client.objects.order_by()[0].ordered_at`

2011-04-22 15:27:28 - latest_client
2010-03-17 21:00:0 - first_client

I need to get the difference between dates in the form of list years and months:
2011(04,03,02,01)
2010(12,11,10,09,08,07,06,05,04,03)

Advice please algorithm, how?

Comment: 1.  Convert from year/month to a 12*year+month index value.  2. Use `range`.  Please code this, **update** the question, and we'll comment on how well you did.

Comment: checked datetime.timedelta ???

Comment: Do you need full dates (e.g. iteration over `datetime.date(year, month, 1)`) or a specialized structure (e.g. iteration over `year, (month, month, month)` structures)?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters, i need datetime.date()

Comment: Ok, i'm try to use range and timedelta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a generator that gives you `datetime.date()` spanning the months between start and end (inclusive)

```
from datetime import date, datetime
def spanning_months(start, end):
    assert start <= end
    current = start.year * 12 + start.month - 1
    end = end.year * 12 + end.month - 1
    while current <= end:
        yield date(current // 12, current % 12 + 1, 1)
        current += 1
```

Demonstration:

```
>>> latest = datetime(2011, 4, 22, 15, 27, 28)
>>> first = datetime(2010, 3, 17, 21, 0, 0)
>>> for d in spanning_months(first, latest):
...     print d
2010-03-01
2010-04-01
2010-05-01
2010-06-01
2010-07-01
2010-08-01
2010-09-01
2010-10-01
2010-11-01
2010-12-01
2011-01-01
2011-02-01
2011-03-01
2011-04-01
```